# Direct sum of subspace

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm confused in finding the solution to the following question.

> Construct three subspaces $M, N_1 \& N_2$ of a vector space $V$ such
>   that $M \oplus N_1 = M \oplus N_2 = V$ but $N_1 \ne N_2$.

Doesn't $M \oplus N_1 = M \oplus N_2$ means that $N_1 = N_2$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Take $V=\mathbb{R}^2$. We know that $V=\{(0,x)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}\oplus \{(y,0)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $V=\{(0,x)|x\in\mathbb{R}\}\oplus \{(y,2y)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ but $\{(y,0)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}\neq \{(y,2y)|y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously not. Take a plane $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$: then *every* line $N$ not contained in $M$ is a direct complement of $N$ (by Grassmann formula, if you want).

In finite dimension, finding a direct complement of $M$ is equivalent to completing a basis of $M$ to a basis of $V$, and this procedure is clearly non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Let $V=R \oplus N_1$ where $N_1 \equiv R$. And let $N_2= sp((1,1))  $ Then $V=R \oplus N_2$ and $N_1 \ne N_2$